# Is there an alternate to CMD in windows to run compiler commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The below command is used by the IAR compiler to compile my project. I have 2 questions here.

1. Is it a Windows CMD command? If no then how can I run this command on windows xp / 7?
2. If it is a Windows CMD command then how can I get it to work? I have already tried adding double quotes. The parameter -I seems to run into trouble.

Below is the command followed by the screenshot of the error.

```
xlink.exe F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI\Obj\Main.r43 F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI\Obj\Platform.r43 -o F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI.d43 -B -IC:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\LIB\ -f C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\config\linker\lnk430F425A.xcl -f C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\config\linker\multiplier.xcl -D_STACK_SIZE=50 -rt C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\lib\dlib\dl430fn.r43 -e_PrintfLarge=_Printf -e_ScanfLarge=_Scanf -D_DATA16_HEAP_SIZE=50 -s __program_start -D_DATA20_HEAP_SIZE=50
```

[image]

Comment: You need quotes around every path with spaces.

Comment: 1) yes it is. 2) you need quotes for every path (with a space inside) and maybe also a space after -I.

Answer (score 0):

`xlink.exe` is not a Windows command like the internal commands of `cmd.exe` or other commands with a separate EXE file installed with Windows into directory `%SystemRoot%\system32`.

`xlink.exe` is a console application to run on Windows, but not with a graphical user interface (GUI), but in a command prompt window also known as console window.

In your case `xlink.exe` was installed with IAR workbench, see [Latest version of XLINK linker](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=16492).

There is also a [IAR Linker and Library Tools Reference Guide](http://supp.iar.com/filespublic/updinfo/005131/xlink.ENU.pdf) (PDF file) explaining all parameters which can be used on running `xlink.exe`.

A console application like `xlink.exe` outputs a short help usually on running it in a command prompt window with `xlink.exe /?` (Windows standard) or `xlink.exe -?` or `xlink.exe --help` (Unix standard and therefore often also working on Windows for applications ported from Unix to Windows).

A space character is a separator between command and its parameters and between each parameter for the command, EXCEPT a string is put in double quotes.

Therefore you need to use:

```
xlink.exe F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI\Obj\Main.r43 F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI\Obj\Platform.r43 -o F:\CP001\Temp\U20EI.d43 -B "-IC:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\LIB\" -f "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\config\linker\lnk430F425A.xcl" -f "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\config\linker\multiplier.xcl" -D_STACK_SIZE=50 -rt "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\430\lib\dlib\dl430fn.r43" -e_PrintfLarge=_Printf -e_ScanfLarge=_Scanf -D_DATA16_HEAP_SIZE=50 -s __program_start -D_DATA20_HEAP_SIZE=50
```

Please note that IAR workbench like most IDE modify environment variable **PATH** on starting a build job by inserting at beginning of the list of directories the path to the directory containing the executables (compiler, assembler, linker, ...) for the build job.

Therefore on running a console application like `xlink.exe` manually from command line or from within a batch file either full path to `xlink.exe` must be specified also on command line / batch file (in double quotes if the file name with file extension and path contains anywhere a space character), or environment variable **PATH** is modified also before in command prompt window / batch file if the user's **PATH** or the system **PATH** was not modified already during installation of IAR workbench.

Open a command prompt window for example by running `cmd.exe` and enter `path` to see which directories are by default for your account included in **PATH**.